# SyncConfiguration deprecated, what is the proper use of SyncUser.configuration()?

Tags: swift, realm

I have started to get the following warning from Realm:

> 'init(user:realmURL:enableSSLValidation:isPartial:urlPrefix:)' is deprecated: Use SyncUser.configuration() instead

I understand what the warning is saying, but I cannot get `SyncUser.configuration()` to work correctly. Here is my current (deprecated) implementation:

```
if let _ = SyncUser.current {
    // already logged in
    let syncConfig = SyncConfiguration(user: SyncUser.current!, realmURL: Settings.Credentials.REALM_URL!)
    let config = Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: syncConfig, objectTypes: [ConfigItem.self, Intersection.self])

    self.database = try! Realm(configuration: config)
}
else {
    let creds = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: Settings.Credentials.REALM_LOGIN, password: Settings.Credentials.REALM_KEY)

    SyncUser.logIn(with: creds, server: Settings.Credentials.AUTH_URL!, onCompletion: { [weak self](user, error) in
        if let _ = user {
            let syncConfig = SyncConfiguration(user: SyncUser.current!, realmURL: Settings.Credentials.REALM_URL!)
            let config = Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: syncConfig, objectTypes: [ConfigItem.self, Intersection.self])

            self?.database = try! Realm(configuration: config)
        } else if let error = error {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
}
```

The two lines `let syncConfig = ......` are where I get the warning. I can get the app to compile correctly, replacing the two config lines like so:

```
let config = SyncUser.current!.configuration(realmURL: Settings.Credentials.REALM_URL!)
```

However, that does not allow me to connect to my synced Realm. Using the above, there is also no way to specify which object types you would like to sync. Has anyone migrated away from the deprecated `SyncConfiguration` way of configuring a synced Realm? It seems like it should be close to what I'm trying, but for some reason it doesn't connect.

**EDIT**

If I use the default `SyncUser.configuration()`, it will at least give me the message that it connected to the endpoint, but the data does not sync. Here is the `config` using the default sync config:

```
let config = SyncUser.current!.configuration()
```

If I add the `realmURL` parameter back in, it no longer gives me the connected to endpoint message. Also, the deprecated method is still what is displayed in the documentation at https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#realms:

```
// Create the configuration
let syncServerURL = URL(string: "realm://localhost:9080/~/userRealm")!
let config = Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: syncServerURL))

// Open the remote Realm
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let config = SyncUser.current!.configuration(realmURL: url, fullSynchronization: false, enableSSLValidation: true, urlPrefix: nil)
```

I got this link from their customer support: https://realm.io/docs/swift/3.7.5/api/Extensions/SyncUser.html#/s:So11RLMSyncUserC10RealmSwiftE13configurationAC0C0C13ConfigurationV10Foundation3URLVSg05realmH0_Sb19fullSynchronizationSb19enableSSLValidationSSSg9urlPrefixtF

Comment: that is the same as `SyncUser.current!.configuration(realmURL: url)` because the rest are default values anyway... have you tried modifying an existing synced Realm to use this configuration?

Comment: Right. I didn't see that you answered your own question within the edit section +1

Comment: @dubstylee I don't see that Edit answered the question; it states that the depreciated error message is resolved, but the data does not sync. Can you update the answer with a bit more code to show the proper way to use SyncUser.configuration() to actually connect to Realm? Otherwise it's just a link only answer.

Comment: @Jay correct, the edit does not answer the question. I still have not been able to get it to work with SyncUser.configuration(). I am still using the deprecated code for now.

Comment: I have been searching answer for this online for months. There seems to be no real way to use any code other than the deprecated code.