# Cannot find SyncConfiguration (or equivalent class for Realm)

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm trying to complete [this tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/android/quick-start-local/) to setup a test realm database.

I'm stuck in the part where SyncConfiguration is defined, like this:

```
SyncConfiguration config = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(app.currentUser(), PARTITION)
    .allowQueriesOnUiThread(true)
    .allowWritesOnUiThread(true)
    .build();
```

Android Studio is not able to determine the two classes shown there, which are supposed to be imported as:

```
import io.realm.SyncConfiguration;
import io.realm.mongodb.sync.SyncConfiguration.Builder;
```

But if these imports are set, the classes aren't found.

Other parts of Realm seem to have succesfully been imported, for example this code:

```
    Realm.init(this);
    String realmName = "My Project";
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().name(realmName).build();
    Realm backgroundThreadRealm = Realm.getInstance(config);
```

Compiles and executes with no problem.

By the way, it seems like SyncConfiguration is already deprecated [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487918/syncconfiguration-deprecated-what-is-the-proper-use-of-syncuser-configuration), so, although it would be very rare, it might have been removed, and instead SyncUser has to be used as shown in that StackOverflow post, but neither it finds this class.

What could I do so I can properly use this classes or use another ones for the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

you might not have connected

```
realm {
syncEnabled = true}
```

in build.gradle Module

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).